# How do I use Git to manage my custom Drupal module code which I use on several sites?

Tags: git, drupal, drupal-7

I'm not sure if this correctly belongs here or on the Drupal StackExchange site.

I work as a sole developer in a small company. We have several Drupal 7 sites. I've built several custom modules which are used on most of the sites. I'm a relative newbie with git.

The sites are in git. The root of each site is its own repository. Pretty much everything except /sites/default/files is in git for each site. I use drush to update contrib modules and core and then commit all changes for that site.

This seems like a simple question but I'm struggling to find the (probably obvious) answer.

How do I structure things so that I maintain my own custom modules in one place with their own repository? Right now I simply have multiple copies of the custom modules on each site. They get committed along with the rest of the site but of course that's not the way to do it. The module code gets out of sync between sites etc. I obviously need to work on the modules in one place and pull the updates into the individual sites.

Should I make one site which is just for my custom module development and create repositories for each of my modules? By that I mean "git init directory_name" from the directory above where my modules are to turn those existing modules into repositories. Then add, commit etc and push to my remote repo.

I'm confused about what I then need on the sites themselves to be able to pull the updates in. Do I need Git submodules on the sites?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should probably set up a master git repo for your modules, keep it on a remote server somewhere (git hub, BitBucket, etc...). Then the workflow would go something like this:

1. Make changes on any of the sites.
2. Commit the changes.
3. Push the changes to the master repo.
4. Pull the changes from the other sites that need these changes.

Comment: Thanks Mark. I do have "bare" repositories for each site on a remote server. It's my own which I connect to with SSH. I'm still a little confused. Lets say I have sites A, B and C and modules X, Y and Z. Lets say I work on module X in site A. Then I commit and push all of site A to the server repo. I then pull those changes to my staging siteA. That's all working. What I don't quite get is how to pull the module X changes (/sites/all/modules/custom/moduleX) to sites B and C.

Comment: Then all you need to do is clone the modules on for each site. The hard part is keeping them all in sync.

Comment: Opps, I saved my comment before it was finished. Maybe a silly question but what do you mean by "clone". Do you mean "clone" in the git sense or just copy to the other sites?

Comment: I mean run the "git clone…" command to get the source from the bare repo. This way all of your sites are pulling from a common base and you don't have to worry about which is the "master". It working a bit more like Perforce or SVN, but that's not all bad. You will be able to make a change on any site, push to the bare repo and then pull from any of the other sites.

Comment: But I push all of SiteA to its repo. That includes everything from the root down. ModuleX is just a small part of that buried several levels down. SiteB is an entirely different site with its own repo from the root down that just happens to also use ModuleX which I want to keep as common code. When I go to my SiteB staging site and pull from the SiteB repo, how do I also pull from just the ModuleX part of SiteA's repo? I think I'm missing something.

Comment: I think this is the right answer although still a little confusing for a git newbie. I was missing the fact that nested git repos work just fine. Now I have my custom modules in their own repos. Those repos are cloned inside whole Drupal sites which have their own repos at their root level. I can work on the modules in any site (although I tend to use one site for module development), commit and push just the module and pull that on any of the other sites. Then I can commit and push a whole site and that commit will include module changes.